# 401 Unauthorized out of nowhere with Jenkins and TFS

Tags: jenkins, tfs, msbuild

**EDIT 2**

Okay, turns out this has nothing to do with TFS or MSBuilder. This is entirely a problem with SonarQube. The SonarQube Service is the one who sends back a 401 (Unauthorized) status not TFS. Since I run 5.4 I have no clue as to how I specify a SonarQube user because in Jenkins both of those fields are greyed out.

---

I am using Jenkins as a Windows Service and about 2 hours ago the service made a successful build. Now, out of seemingly nowhere, Jenkins keeps reporting 401 (Unauthorized) no matter which build job I try to start.

- They all start a SonarQube scanner first
- Run MSBuild
- In order for SonarQube to read the analysis I have to run a rebuild command
- Run the End SonarQube analysis step and it collects the data to put on our SonarQube portal.

What I don't understand is that the last change I made to anything, was to go delete a file from an ASP project and now none of the jobs work, even those that have nothing to do with this ASP project. All the projects are stored on our Team Foundation Server (not locally hosted).

The only thing that really changed was that we wanted the IP of the Jenkins and SonarQube services to be accessible outside of the server they are hosted on so we made two sites on the local IIS and made a DNS to point at those. Reading into the error log I first see status 302 which is a redirection, before I reach 402. When I go to "Configure Jenkins" I am told that my proxy settings failed...or something along those lines.

Any idea what might cause this behaviour?

**EDIT**

Here is a part of the error log:

> INFO: SCM changes detected in CSharp Build Job. Triggering  #1
>
> Apr 20, 2016 11:04:08 AM com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.httpclient.DefaultHTTPClientFactory logHTTPClientConfiguration
>
> INFO: HttpClient configured for https://omitted.visualstudio.com/, authenticating as it@omitted.dk
>
> Apr 20, 2016 11:04:10 AM com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService executeSOAPRequestInternal
>
> INFO: SOAP method='GetRegistrationEntries', status=302, content-length=0, server-wait=1164 ms, parse=0 ms, total=1164 ms, throughput=0 B/s, uncompressed
>
> Apr 20, 2016 11:04:11 AM com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector processWWWAuthChallenge
>
> INFO: Failure authenticating with BASIC @omitted.visualstudio.com:443
>
> Apr 20, 2016 11:04:11 AM com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService executeSOAPRequestInternal
>
> INFO: SOAP method='GetRegistrationEntries', status=401, content-length=0, server-wait=578 ms, parse=0 ms, total=578 ms, throughput=0 B/s, uncompressed
>
> Apr 20, 2016 11:04:11 AM com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSTeamProjectCollection getServerDataProvider
>
> WARNING: Error getting data provider
>
> com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TFSUnauthorizedException: Access denied connecting to TFS server https://omitted.visualstudio.com/ (authenticating as it@omitted.dk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the solution. It's so stupid I can't believe I didn't think of it.

In my `SonarQube.Analysis.xml` found at

`...Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\MSBuild_2.0\SonarQube.Analysis.xml`

I remembered that I had the username and password written and at some point I went and changed that in SonarQube from the default values to something else. That made all the builds break.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the Server URL from `https://omitted.visualstudio.com/` to `https://omitted.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection`. And use Personal access tokens or Alternate credentials for User name and password. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The setup is already as you suggest. With a public token and everything http://puu.sh/ozOox/1a4192b205.png

Comment: You may try to install a Safe Restart Plugin and restart Jenkins to see whether it works.

Comment: Hm, that didn't do anything. But I am being told that my proxy setup is broken and [this page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+says+my+reverse+proxy+setup+is+broken)  shows up as the solution. Would that have anything to do with it?